# How to change keys of a dictionary in julia?

Tags: dictionary, julia

I want to replace the values of one key of a dictionary with a column of dataframe. While the values in the second key are repeated if any of the values from first key are repeated.

For example:

```
using DataFrames
d = d = Dict(:1 => 2, :2=>3, :3=>4)
df = DataFrame(a = [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                b = [7,6,5,4,3,2],
                c = [9,8,7,6,6,8])

#Output
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 4 entries:
  3 => 4
  2 => 7
  1 => 6

#Dataframe
8 rows × 3 columns
a   b   c
Int64   Int64   Int64
1   7   9
1   6   8
2   5   7
2   4   6
3   3   6
3   2   8
```

I want to replace the keys of `Dict = d` with `df.a`, to produce the following dictionary.

```
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 6 entries:
 1 => 6
 1 => 6
 2 => 7
 2 => 7
 3 => 4
 3 => 4
```

May I know how to achieve this operation?

### Update

Firstly, thanks @gTcV for the amazing suggestion and great help, highly appreciate it !!!

Just to extract the values one can follow the above post mentioned by @gTcV.
However, to achieve the above dataframe operation one may use the following snippet:

```
using DataFrames
d = d = Dict(:1 => 2, :2=>3, :3=>4)
df = DataFrame(a = [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                b = [7,6,5,4,3,2],
                c = [9,8,7,6,6,8])
df[!, c] = [i=d[i] for i in df[:, :a]]

Output: --> 
6×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      7      2
   2 │     1      6      2
   3 │     2      5      3
   4 │     2      4      3
   5 │     3      3      4
   6 │     3      2      4
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `Dict`s do not allow repeated keys. You need to choose another container for the output. Would `Vector{Pair}` do?

Comment: @gTcV thanks for the response, is it possible to extract just the values as shown in the expected output? As my goal is to just extract the values and ensure that for all the similar keys they remain same.

Comment: Sure, you can just do `for a in df[:,1]; println("$a => $(d[a])"); end`.

Comment: @gTcV thanks this solved the problem, highly appreciate the help!!!!!

Comment: @gTcV you could probably write an answer to this post from your successful comments that can then be validated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dicts` do not allow repeated keys, so what you ask for is not possible. If it's just about the output, you can do the following:

```
for a in df[:,1]
    println("$a => $(d[a])")
end
```